# Check for multiple columns with Single Value using SELECT query

Tags: sql, spring-mvc

I have a table fruits. Now in UI, I provide a single field for a search criteria. Using this single Search criteria, i want to search in multiple columns of Fruits Table.

Consider Fruits table contains Columns ID,Desc,Price,Quant,Stock. Here Price,Quant are integers and Stock is a varchar.

I have tried the below query which returns the results, but i am worried about the performance.

Suppose assume user enters 2 in the field provided in UI and clicks on search then query will be as shown below

```sql
select ID, Desc, Price, Quant, Stock 
from Fruits 
where Price = '2' 
or Quant = '2' 
or stock = '2'
```

Is this the right way to search for multiple columns of same table? Also will be any effect on performance?

Comment: what is the db? mssql?

Comment: i want it for db2

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as varchar?

Comment: If possible, you should avoid numeric value comparisons done with strings.  If your code generates the `SQL` dynamically, you may want to modify your query to only search on numeric fields if the search value is numeric.

Comment: is there any rule ? if Price is 2 then others are null?

Comment: yes price can be 2 and others can be null or viceversa,also  both can be 2.

Comment: Just fix data types, otherwise your query is fine. Go for numeric data types wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to be sure that the types are compatible.  In all likelihood these values are numbers, so drop the quotes:

```
select ID, Desc, Price, Quant, Stock 
from Fruits f
where Price = 2 or Quant = 2 or stock = 2;
```

This can more simply be written as:

```
select ID, Desc, Price, Quant, Stock 
from Fruits f
where 2 in (Price, Quant, Stock);
```

but that will not help performance.

In most databases your query will require a full table scan -- although some databases support a particular type of index scan called a skip scan which can help.

The only way I can think to get around that is to have a separate index on each column:

```
create index idx_fruits_price on fruits(price);
create index idx_fruits_quant on fruits(quant, price);
create index idx_fruits_stock on fruits(stock, quant, price);
```

(You'll see why the extra columns are helpful.)

And then use `union all`:

```
select ID, Desc, Price, Quant, Stock 
from Fruits f
where Price = 2
union all
select ID, Desc, Price, Quant, Stock 
from Fruits f
where quant = 2 and price <> 2
union all
select ID, Desc, Price, Quant, Stock 
from Fruits f
where stock = 2 and price <> 2 and stock <> 2;
```

Each of the subqueries can use one of the indexes.  Because of the inequalities, the results are exclusive -- assuming the column values are not `null`.  If `null`s are allowed, the logic can be adjusted to handle that.